# Statistics $E[V]$ Problems

Tags: statistics

I have 2 statistics problems I am stuck on. Can anyone help me?

1. Use the definition in Expression 3.13 to prove that $V(aX+b)=a^2\sigma_x^2$. [Hint: With $h(x)=aX+b$, $E[h(X)=a\mu+b$ where $\mu=E(X)$.] Expression 3.1 is:

$V(ax+b)=\sigma_{aX+b}^2=a^2\cdot\sigma_X^2$
And:
$\sigma_{aX+b}=|a|\cdot\sigma_X.$

2. Write a general rule for $E(X-c)$ where c is a constant. What happens when you let $c=\mu$, the expected value of $X$.

I can prove number #1 using the shortcut identity, but I don't think that's what it wants, I'm not sure where to start for #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a strong hint for #2. Take a data set, then subtract (or add, even) the same number from each point. What happens to the mean? Try to experiment with specific values.

Comment: Oh wait is it just asking for me to say, for any constant $ c $, $ E(x-c)=E(x)-c $ and that when $ c=\mu $ that this turns into $ 0 $?

Comment: Boom. Done! That's it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Any ideas for #1 using the expression and hints?